# image on apache or weblogic interview question

Tags: html, apache, plugins, weblogic

I was asked an interview question where how can I tell if an image is coming from apache or weblogic. How can I determine if it is not a part of the war file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is a specific rule within the web server for static images (URI based) so just by looking at the full URL of the image, you should be able to tell if it's from Apache or WebLogic.

If the Apache / WebLogic proxy-plugin configuration seems overly complex, you could just try loading the image and tail the access logs on the WebLogic application server to see if the image is being served from it.

If that doesn't work, you can enabled the debug logs for the WebLogic proxy-plugin on apache and monitor the details of all outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

If the question meant, from the front-end i.e. browser, can you tell whether the image was served from Apache or Weblogic - it would be from the URL.
I'm assuming you don't have access to the weblogic logs in this case.

Check the source for the other URLs in the application, such as JSPs and JS files. Usually the JSPs will be prepended by the web-app context-root URL, and if the images are served from weblogic the same context-root will be present.

If they are served from Apache, then it is likely to have no context-root or a different context-root like /static